# how to concat join by qb in doctrine?

Tags: doctrine

I want to add a join to my query in if condition but it returned an error.
how we can do it in doctrine?
is there any thing like:
  $qb->andWhere('p.$gender = :g')->setParameter('g', $gender);
 for join in doctrine symfony??

```
   $qb->select("p")->from("PfmSanadBundle:Person",  "p");

    if ((isset($province) && trim($province) !== '') && (isset($City) && trim($City) !== '')){
        $qb->join("p" ,"students", "ps")
            ->join("ps" ,"organization", "po")
            ->join("po" ,"cityProvince", "pc")
            ->join("pc" ,"province", "pp");
    }
   if ((isset($province) && trim($province) !== '') && !isset($City)) {
        $qb->join("p.students", "ps")
            ->join("ps.organization", "po");
    }
    $res = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

error (postman):

> "error": {
>       "code": 500,
>       "message": "Internal Server Error",
>       "exception": [
>         {
>           "message": "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 49 near 'p students INNER': Error: Class 'p' is not defined.",
>           "class": "Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException",
>           "trace": [
>             {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join method usage is following

```
// Example - $qb->join('u.Group', 'g', Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('u.status_id', '?1'))
// Example - $qb->join('u.Group', 'g', 'WITH', 'u.status = ?1')
// Example - $qb->join('u.Group', 'g', 'WITH', 'u.status = ?1', 'g.id')
public function join($join, $alias, $conditionType = null, $condition = null, $indexBy = null);
```

Thus following lines

```
$qb->join("p" ,"students", "ps")
    ->join("ps" ,"organization", "po")
    ->join("po" ,"cityProvince", "pc")
    ->join("pc" ,"province", "pp");
```

change to

```
$qb->join("p.students", "ps")
    ->join("ps.organization", "po")
    ->join("po.cityProvince", "pc")
    ->join("pc.province", "pp");
```

Comment: Thanks, every thing is ok now!